# Wildcard Certificate stuck on server?

Tags: ssl-certificate

This is my first time asking something in here.

Anyways, I have this problem and have been poking at it for a couple of weeks now. We use a website that is a website hosting and management company for Drupal and Wordpress. We have two custom domains for this website one is a base domain example.com and a subdomain of www.example.com. They told us to add a CNAME that redirects from the default domain = live-example.magazine.io over to www.example.com in our internal DNS server. We did that and it is working fine connections are great and everyone is able to access. This is where the problem starts, My boss turned on HTTPS live environment on these domains that are ours by the way and now we are having issues with a certificate. Customers from outside our network are able to get to the website and the correct certificate shows up on the website. Whenever anybody from inside our network tries to get to www.example.com it gives us a  SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN error and we have to confirm an exception for people to get in.

I compared the two certificates the correct certificate that should show up and is seen by people outside our network is a cloudfare certificate. The certificate that shows up internally is a DigiCert SHA2 secure server CA certificate with a wildcard mask of *.magazine.io

I do understand that it is trying to look for the cloudfare certificate but the *.magazine.io is somehow stopping it from getting to it. My boss updated the certificate for our website of www.example.com.

I talked to support about this and they keep saying that somehow that Digicert certificate is stuck on our network which makes sense since it is only internally where we are having problems but I have taken a look at the certifications data stores in our DNS servers and the Digicert certificate did show up but I deleted them and flushed the DNS and it did not seem to work.

So my question is do you guys think this is something stuck on my network and if so where would it be stuck at(have not had any luck on finding it so far) or do you think maybe that bad certificate comes attached to the default domain that they gave us and told us to add a cname record for it. Also when I open up a web browser and input the URL https://live-example.magazine.io it does not give me a security error and the lock turns green but that happens because of the wildcard certificate which has the name *magazine.io on it so it shows up fine but when I put www.example.com it does not give me the correct updated certificate.

Anyways, if you have had this problem before or if you have an idea of what it might be any input would really be appreciated I am kind of stuck on this problem here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use `CNAME` or `A` type record in your DNS doesn't matter. There's no evil DNS kidnapping any certificates as they work on different protocol.

The problem is web server related. In plain HTTP connection browser sends the hostname from address bar in `Host:`  header and the web server chooses the correct virtual host configuration based on that information.

TLS connection is established before this information is ever sent, causing the web server to use the first certificate it finds in your configuration, in this case the wildcard certificate. Then, after receiving the headers, it can still serve you with the correct site.

Formerly the only way to address this problem was to have different IP address for every sertificate. That was until [Server Name Indication SNI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4366#section-3.1), an extension of TLS which allows the client to include the requested hostname in the first message of its SSL handshake.

SNI has been there since OpenSSL 0.9.8f from Oct 2007. It has been supported by all major browsers for years now. You can easily configure it on [Apache](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI), it has been supported by [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) since 0.5.23 and was introduced in [IIS 8.0](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability).

Comment: Hello. I appreciate the feedback. I have heard of SNI before I just was not sure if this was the way to go. Although, we do not actually host any websites from our internal network. We use a web hosting service from an external company they pretty much give us an alias and we just create a cname in our internal DNS to direct towards that domain. Do you think SNI would work in this scenario? I am actually thinking that because this is another domain and we are pretty much just redirecting from inside our network I wonder if the conflict could be coming from there. I appreciate your help!

Comment: The web server doesn't care where the DNS is set. It doesn't even know it. The mismatch giving the error is always between `Host:` header sent by the browser and the common name (or DNS aliases in `subjectAltName`) of the certificate.

Comment: I understand. I appreciate the help.